# Unable to update release iOS app with dev build: "*AppName* is already installed"

Tags: ios, xcode, installation, bundle-identifier

I'm trying to test user data migration from a released app (installed from App Store) to new development build.

But when I'm installing IPA on the device, I get an error:

> *AppName* is already installed.
>   *AppName* has the same Bundle ID as *AppName* and can't be installed. To continue, delete *AppName* from your device and start again.

Any ideas, how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: in your question has answer. delete and install again.

Comment: I want to test data migration. When users will update release build to new build, data should migrate successfully. That's why I'm trying to install dev over release.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this issue. Mine was a fairly specific case but figured I should post a reply just incase someone else runs into the same thing.

I was using Hockey, now App Center, for testing. With my last build I was unable to upgrade in place. When I would attempt to install from App Center I would see the "{AppName} is already installed. To install {app}, delete {app} from your device and try again." After trying a number of things to fix this I was never able to get it working. I instead put my app on TestFlight where I was able to upgrade in place. We ended up shipping as is and did not have any problems upgrading in the field.

My issue was a combination of both changing distribution profiles and upgrading from the Hockey SDK -> App Center in the same build.

Anyone running into this using App Center. I suggest double checking if you have the issue on TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS allows identifies app by their bundleId.

- No two apps on app store can have the same bundleId
- No two apps on a phone can have the same bundleId (more applicable during development)

If you use the same bundle-id, between your QA and Prod/App store builds then at a given time you can only have one app installed on your device.

Two solutions:

- delete the existing app on your phone and install it again
- use distinct bundleIds for different environments.